# Activity Recognition API get state of user in background

Tags: android, activity-recognition

So, I am using Activity Recognition API and I am measuring Still, walking, on foot - you get the idea, for my app.

Now the issue I am having is when I quit the app it doesn't do it in background, I want to count the number of hours a person was **inactive**  or **still** during a day, How can I achieve this. I am already using a **broadcast reciever** with Activity Recognition API.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in Advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a background service
activity -> background service ->start activity detection

Comment: Could you be more specific ?